# Lato font broken in FF when using latin-ext characters

Tags: firefox, web, google-fonts

I have developed a site in Polish using the 'Lato' Google Font (supports the latin-extended character subset). My site is http://www.innova.uno
I have placed the code from GF website in my theme's ` section:

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,700,700i,900,900i&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">`

When I open the site in Chrome, all text are displayed correctly. But when opening the site in Firefox the Polish characters are changed to Times New Roman - **but only** in the Lato font based texts - headers (see screenshot: http://pl.tinypic.com/r/etrsxj/9) - other latin-ext fonts work well.

I don't know if any of you will see the site in FF the same way, but if anybody does and could have a slight idea why is this happening - please give me a hint! :)
Thx.